# How to merge 2 inputs to 1 using bootstrap css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 `<input>` fields next to each other. The thing I want to achieve is similar to the for class `class="input-group-addon"` in Bootstrap - unfortunately it's only for `<span>`.
How can I merge these inputs to one?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30247/)

This is what I am looking for:

[image: target]

Answer (score 3):

Try this
css:

```
#firstInput {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
#secondInput {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-left:0px;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="firstInput">First Input</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="firstInput" name="firstInput" ng-model="obj.firstInput" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" id="secondInput" name="secondInput" ng-model="obj.secondInput" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

link https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30252/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input 
       type="text"
       id="firstInput" 
       name="firstInput" 
       ng-model="obj.firstInput" class="form-control">
      <input 
       type="text" 
       id="secondInput" 
       name="secondInput" 
       ng-model="obj.secondInput" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="numbers" name="numbers" type="number" ng-model="obj.num" class="form-control" min="0" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

body {
  margin: 10px;
}

#firstInput, #secondInput {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#firstInput {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}

#secondInput {
  border-left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems nice, but the problem is that these inputs have col-md-4, i'd like to have one col-md-2, and second col-md-4

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this with custom CSS:

**CSS:**

```
.input-group .form-control {
  width:45%;
  margin-right:0%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput"
    placeholder="fname">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput1"
    placeholder="lname">
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/suchit/DTcHh/30273/)

Another Not exact but similar way can be using form-inline.

```css
.form-group{
float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group" style="float:left;">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email" style="border-top-right-radius: 0px;border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" >
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" style="border-top-left-radius: 0px;border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;border-left:0px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My inputs have corner rounded

Comment: Hm it doesn't work for me in code. http://prntscr.com/eegkvs
Also if there is a label above the first field, then it looks even worst...

Answer (score 0):

**Combine bootstrap's form-controls/input fields**

```css
.form-control{
border-radius: 0 !important;
}
.input-group .form-control {
  margin-right:0%;
  width:50% !important;
  /* width:100px !important;*/
}
.input-group .form-control:last-child{
margin-left:-1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30255/

Use below css to get the desired output

```
.form-group {
  float: left;
}
.form-group #secondInput{
      margin-top: 4px;
      border-radius:0;
      width: 300px;
}

.form-group #firstInput{
      border-radius:0;
      width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="padding:0;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstInput"></label>
      <input type="text" id="firstInput" name="firstInput" ng-model="obj.firstInput" class="form-control" style="border-radius:0">
    </div>
</div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="padding:0;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="secondInput"> </label>
      <input type="text" id="secondInput" name="secondInput" ng-model="obj.secondInput" class="form-control" style="border-radius:0">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because one textbox has a text, while the other doesn't. If you both put something in the label, or remove it, it will be straight

Comment: You could explain your reason first before downvoting.

Comment: I think I clarified in screenshot what I expect. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uUbi.png